# Как провести слияние двух строк в PHP

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Прошу помощи решить данную проблему.

Есть две строки, пример:

1) Строка с путями к картинкам (разделенные запятыми):

```
images/img1.jpg,images/img2.jpg,images/img3.jpg
```

2) Строка с названиями картинок (разделенные запятыми):

```
img-name1,img-name2,img-name3
```

Как провести слияние, чтобы получить следующее:

```
images/img1.jpg||img-name1,images/img2.jpg||img-name2,images/img3.jpg||img-name3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что пришло в голову первым:

```
<?php

    $str1 = 'images/img1.jpg,images/img2.jpg,images/img3.jpg';
    $str2 = 'img-name1,img-name2,img-name3';

    $arr1 = explode(',', $str1);
    $arr2 = explode(',', $str2);
    $finish_arr = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($arr1);$i++){
        $finish_arr[$i] = $arr1[$i].'|'.$arr2[$i];
    }

    $finish_str = implode(',', $finish_arr);
    print_r($finish_str);
?>
```

С начало с помощью метода `explode` создаем массив из строки.
Потом пройдя по циклу, прикрепляем значение двух массивов. А в конце делаем обратное с помощью метода `implode`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!

Answer (score 0):

С учётом того, что название картинок не меняется:

```
$images = explode(",", "images/img1.jpg,images/img2.jpg,images/img3.jpg");

$result = array_reduce($images, function($result, $image) {
  $imageNumber = filter_var($image, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  return $result .= sprintf("%s||img-name%s,", $image, $imageNumber);
});

$result = rtrim($result, ',');
```